# awk searching for multiple fields

Tags: bash, search, awk

I encountered a difficulty during my assignment and would like some clarification.

I have the following code to find book by author and title (or part of title e.g find Lego War VI and return 2 result /  find Scissorhands and find 3 results).
However, if author is RETURN, find only by title. And if title is RETURN, find only by author.

- The problem comes when I have to use awk to find both author and title.
- Can anyone guide me on the search_both function? the problem is that I am unable to search both fields and print out result.

For example. If I were to type in author = Lego and title = Lego Wars VI there should be only 1 field found,  which will print out.

Lego Wars VI – Lego Legacy, Lego Company, $15.98, 20, 15

```
#!/bin/bash

function search_title
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" '$1 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}

function search_author
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Author" '$2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}

function search_both
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" search1="$Author" '$1 ~ search && $2 ~ search1 { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}

read -p $'Title: ' Title
read -p $'Author: ' Author

if [ "$Title" == "" ];
then
search_author
elif [ "$Author" == "" ];
then
search_title
else
search_both
fi
```

So the format of books.txt is `title:author:price:quantity:sold`
Here is a sample of input if anyone would like to see:

> Lego Wars VI – Lego Legacy:Lego Company:$15.98:20:15
>
> Lego Wars VI – Return of the Lego:Fake Company:$8.05:30:20
>
> C++ for noobs:John Scissorhands:$15.01:10:5
>
> Java for noobs:Mary Scissorhands:$16.02:20:15
>
> VB.NET  for noobs:Edward Scissorhands:$17.03:30:25

Comment: what is "the problem"?

Comment: Have you tried using a `-v` for the search1 field in that function?  When the arg isn't passed in, then you're matching on 'search1' which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks i realize that now after you guys pointed it out! thanks alot. careless me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use shell variables directly in awk but pass them to awk using `-v` switch.

You can search for multiple fields in an awk command:

```
awk -v title="$title" -v author="$auhtor" '$1 ~ title && $2 ~ author {print}' file
```

Comment: Thanks i realize that now after you guys pointed it out! thanks alot. careless me :D